# click on background image and link to external website

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to set body background image as a link? So when somebody click on anywhere outside the content area, it will go to another website.

Comment: I hate sites that do this, so I wouldn't, but it should be pretty easy.  What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/xzuEA/2/ , you just need to add background block with onclick event

```
<div id="fakebody">

</div>
```

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

div#fakebody {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
}
```

```
$(function() {
    $("#fakebody").click(function() {
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, but when I clicked anywhere on my site, it went to another site. I just want to link to other places when somebody click outside my content area.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in html/css only:

```
<body>

<!-- YOUR WEBSITES HTML -->

<a href="YOUR LINK" target="_blank" id="background"></a>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
#background {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:0; // NOTE: YOUR OTHER ELEMENTS MUST BE ABOVE z-index: 0 TO MAKE IT A BACKGROUND
    background:url(your/path/to/background-image.png);
}
```

Comment: display:block, and width/height 100%, to avoid z-index must work fine too :)

Comment: I just had a try. When a page is longer than your screen, which needs scroll, the bottom part is not linking. I got it worked by setting position:fixed. Cheers.